# Fetching number of items from mongoDB in VueJS

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, fetch

I need to get an overview of number of locations from my database. I was able to fetched only the data - ID, location name, etc...but I need the actual number of how many they are instead.

I used this in my template :

```
  <div :class="['col-1, registered-locations']">
    <p v-for="location in locations" :key="location">{{location}}</p>
  </div>
```

And in the script part I just created locations as an empty array.

As I mentioned, I am fetching the details about my locations right now. How can I convert it into number ? It is my second week in VueJS and I am still confused about some stuff.

Comment: Can't you use [`Array.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) to get the size of the array? I.e. `locations.length` should return the number of locations.

Comment: @Terry, yes, but the thing is I am getting the output number as many times as many items is in my DB. Example: I have 3 locations, so number 3 is printed 3 times.

Comment: You shouldn't be using it in a `v-for` loop then. Just do `<span>{{ locations.length }}</span>` and see what you get ;)